# Problems with accessing camera with targetSdkVersion 25?

Tags: android, target-sdk

I have an app that uses camera it works fine when I compile it with `targetSdkVersion 23`, but when I try to use `version 25` I get this error:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG_1093948364.jpg exposed beyond app
>   through ClipData.Item.getUri()

This is the code that I'm using:

```
private void showCameraAction() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                getString(R.string.mis_permission_rationale_write_storage),
                REQUEST_STORAGE_WRITE_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            try {
                mTmpFile = FileUtils.createTmpFile(getActivity());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (mTmpFile != null && mTmpFile.exists()) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTmpFile));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.mis_error_image_not_exist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.mis_msg_no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void requestPermission(final String permission, String rationale, final int requestCode){
    if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle(R.string.mis_permission_dialog_title)
                .setMessage(rationale)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.mis_permission_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.mis_permission_dialog_cancel, null)
                .create().show();
    }else{
        requestPermissions(new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGE_WRITE_ACCESS_PERMISSION){
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            showCameraAction();
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: please check this  https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0  and also refer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Please provide solutions as answers rather than updates to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FileUtils.createTmpFile(getActivity());` probably uses file:// URI to share file with other app(in your case camera).

Android versions greater then 24 use content:// URIs instead, and will throw this exception when you try to share a file directly using the file:// URI.

A content URI allows you to grant read and write access using temporary access permissions

Take a look at [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: A couple of lines below that i'm making a Uri (which links say is the problem), and i tried to write it like this: `Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MultiImageSelectorFragment.this, MultiImageSelectorFragment.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider" , mTmpFile);`  but im getting an error with `getApplicationContext()` which is _Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'_ . any thought on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Changed this:

```
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTmpFile));
```

To this:

```
            //getActivity() because its a fragment
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                    getActivity().getPackageName()
                    , mTmpFile);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

And it worked.